# Testing Xtext language with OSGi anf Maven?

Tags: maven, testing, osgi, xtext

I am developping an Xtext language (named "thezenfra" in the stack below). Within a class in this language I use a bundle in the form of a JAR (named "thpackme" in the stack below). I added it in the MANIFEST.MF using "Bundle-ClassPath:". I am using maven to maintain my project. I use tycho-surefire plugin to execute the tests. When maven enters testing I got this errors. It seems that it does not find the included JAR. Do you see where my problem come from ?

```
[INFO] --- tycho-surefire-plugin:1.0.0:test (default-test) @ org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests ---
[INFO] Command line:
    [/home/okokhome/dev/tools/jdk/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/bin/java, -Dosgi.noShutdown=false, -Dosgi.os=linux, -Dosgi.ws=gtk, -Dosgi.arch=x86_64, -javaagent:/home/okok/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.1/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/okokhome/dev/main/eclipse/phd/ThezenFRA/org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests/target/jacoco.exec, -Dosgi.clean=true, -jar, /home/okokhome/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/1.4.0.v20161219-1356/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar, -data, /home/okokhome/dev/main/eclipse/phd/ThezenFRA/org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests/target/work/data, -install, /home/okokhome/dev/main/eclipse/phd/ThezenFRA/org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests/target/work, -configuration, /home/okokhome/dev/main/eclipse/phd/ThezenFRA/org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests/target/work/configuration, -application, org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest, -testproperties, /home/okokhome/dev/main/eclipse/phd/ThezenFRA/org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests/target/surefire.properties]

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraParsingTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.022 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraParsingTest
org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraParsingTest  Time elapsed: 5.004 sec  <<< ERROR!
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.atlanmod.thezenfra.thezenFRA.ThezenFRAPackage
  at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.scoping.ThezenfraScopeProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.atlanmod.thezenfra.scoping.ThezenfraScopeProvider
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.scoping.batch.IBatchScopeProvider
    for field at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.typesystem.internal.AbstractBatchTypeResolver.scopeProvider(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.typesystem.internal.CachingBatchTypeResolver
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.typesystem.IBatchTypeResolver
    for field at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.compiler.ElementIssueProvider$Factory.typeResolver(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.compiler.ElementIssueProvider$Factory
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.compiler.IElementIssueProvider$Factory
    for field at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.compiler.ErrorSafeExtensions.issueProviderFactory(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.compiler.ErrorSafeExtensions
    for field at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.compiler.JvmModelGenerator._errorSafeExtensions(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.compiler.JvmModelGenerator
    for field at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmModelCompleter.generator(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmModelCompleter
    for field at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmModelAssociator.completer(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmModelAssociator.class(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmModelAssociator
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.ILogicalContainerProvider
    for field at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.validation.XbaseValidator.logicalContainerProvider(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.xtext.service.MethodBasedModule.configure(MethodBasedModule.java:57)
  while locating org.atlanmod.thezenfra.validation.ThezenfraValidator
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.atlanmod.thezenfra.thezenFRA.ThezenFRAPackage
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.scoping.ThezenfraScopeProvider.<init>(ThezenfraScopeProvider.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:737)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:737)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:737)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:204)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:198)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:198)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:179)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider$1.createInjector(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:39)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.ThezenfraStandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration(ThezenfraStandaloneSetupGenerated.java:23)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider.internalCreateInjector(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:41)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider.getInjector(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:29)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider.setupRegistry(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.testing.XtextRunner.methodBlock(XtextRunner.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.run(HeadlessTestApplication.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)


2) Error injecting method, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thepackme/xtext/thepackME/ThepackMEPackage
  at org.eclipse.xtext.validation.AbstractInjectableValidator.register(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.xtext.service.MethodBasedModule.configure(MethodBasedModule.java:57)
  while locating org.atlanmod.thezenfra.validation.ThezenfraValidator
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thepackme/xtext/thepackME/ThepackMEPackage
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.thezenFRA.impl.ThezenFRAPackageImpl.init(ThezenFRAPackageImpl.java:373)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.thezenFRA.ThezenFRAPackage.<clinit>(ThezenFRAPackage.java:59)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.validation.AbstractThezenfraValidator.getEPackages(AbstractThezenfraValidator.java:16)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.validation.AbstractInjectableValidator.register(AbstractInjectableValidator.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector$1.invoke(SingleMethodInjector.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:204)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:198)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:198)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:179)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider$1.createInjector(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:39)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.ThezenfraStandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration(ThezenfraStandaloneSetupGenerated.java:23)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider.internalCreateInjector(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:41)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider.getInjector(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:29)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider.setupRegistry(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.testing.XtextRunner.methodBlock(XtextRunner.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.run(HeadlessTestApplication.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thepackme.xtext.thepackME.ThepackMEPackage cannot be found by org.atlanmod.thezenfra_1.0.0.201904292021
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 71 more

16 errors
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:183)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider$1.createInjector(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:39)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.ThezenfraStandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration(ThezenfraStandaloneSetupGenerated.java:23)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider.internalCreateInjector(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:41)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider.getInjector(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:29)
    at org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraInjectorProvider.setupRegistry(ThezenfraInjectorProvider.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.testing.XtextRunner.methodBlock(XtextRunner.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.run(HeadlessTestApplication.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  ThezenfraParsingTest.org.atlanmod.thezenfra.tests.ThezenfraParsingTest » Creation Gu...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: make sure your build.properties is correct, includes the lib, and does not have warnings.

Comment: The `Bundle-ClassPath` is not considered by Maven. You have to make sure that your dependencies are available on Mavens classpath. You can debug this with `mvn -X`.